# Error in template function (using Boost.Tuples)

Tags: c++, templates, boost, function-templates, boost-tuples

```
#include <list>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>

template<class InputIterator>
void f(InputIterator it)
{
    typedef boost::tuple<typename InputIterator::value_type, int> Pair;
    std::list<Pair> paired;
    typename std::list<Pair>::const_iterator output;
    for(output=paired.begin(); output!=paired.end(); ++output)
    {
        output->get<1>();
    }
}
```

I'm getting libraries with this template function.   Gcc 4.1.2 ([codepad.org](http://za3k.codepad.org/9cVciWLA)) reports the following error:

```
In function 'void f(InputIterator)':
Line 12: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

Could someone more experienced with templates offer advice?  Either the problem or key phrases to research myself?  This has me stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `get` is a function template and the type of `output` is dependent upon the template parameter `InputIterator`, you need to use the `template` keyword:

```
output->template get<1>();
```

The [Comeau C++ Template FAQ](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/techtalk/templates/#templateprefix) has a good description of why this is necessary.

Comment: Huh.  I did not even know that keyword existed (in that context--obviously it's up top).  Thanks.